# Angular2 using functions in router data?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I think the problem should be clear with this pseudo code. Can't find any solution for this. How to solve this?

Current working route:

```
{
    path: ':xyzType',
    component: SuperSpecialComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {

      /* ENUM 1 for XOR */
      authPermissionType: authPermissionType["XOR"],

      permissions: [
        'add:xyzType1',
        'edit:xyzType1',

        'add:xyzType2',
        'edit:xyzType2'
      ]
    },
}
```

I want the permissions to be set dependently from the route parameter 'xzyType'. Should be something like this:

```
{
    path: ':xyzType',
    component: SuperSpecialComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {

      /* ENUM 1 for XOR */
      authPermissionType: authPermissionType["XOR"],

      permissions: function(this_route.param['xyzType']) {
          if(this_route.param['xyzType'] == 'type1' {
              return [
                  'add:xyzType1',
                  'edit:xyzType1'
              ]
          } 
          else if(this_route.param['xyzType'] == 'type2' {
              return [
                  'add:xyzType2',
                  'edit:xyzType2'
              ]
          } 
      }
    },
}
```

Comment: I think what you want is a resolver https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: Yep you definitely want to use a resolve here. It's too bad how verbose they are compared to angular one resolves, especially in UI router. But then again the same thing could be said about everything in the entire framework

Answer (score 0):

So I tried building up a resolver for this ending up with another problem:

```
{
    path: ':xyzType',
    component: SuperSpecialComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {

      /* ENUM 1 for XOR */
      authPermissionType: authPermissionType["XOR"],

      permissions: {
        "type1": [
          "add:xyzType1",
          "edit:xyzType1"
        ],
        "type2": [
          "add:xyzType2",
          "edit:xyzType2"
        ]
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      permissions: PermissionsResolver
    }
}
```

Inside the resolver I check the route params and return the needed permissions by using this code:

```
switch(route.params[xyzType]) {
  case 'type1':
    return route.data['permissions']['type1'];

  case 'type2':
    return route.data['permissions']['type2'];
}
```

The problem is AuthGuard already checks the permissions even though the resolve is not finished. Is there a way how I could tell the AuthGuard to wait for the permissions to change?

Comment: You can share an service with an observable between the `AuthGuard` and the `Resolver` that notifies when resolve is finished. Please don't post follow-up questions as answer. Please edit your question instead and add the info there.

Comment: ok I tried for several hours now ... how the hell do I get a service with an observable to notify when Resolver is finished?!